# Android app won't return result from VB.NET WCF Service

Tags: .net, android, vb.net, wcf, json

here is my WCF server code (VB.NET)...

**Service1.svc**

```
Public Class Service1
Implements IService1

Public Sub New()
End Sub

Public Function GetText() As String Implements IService1.GetText
    Return String.Format("YO MTV ROCKS!")
End Function

Public Function GetData(ByVal value As Integer) As String Implements IService1.GetData
    Return String.Format("You entered: {0}", value)
End Function

Public Function GetDataUsingDataContract(ByVal composite As CompositeType) As CompositeType Implements IService1.GetDataUsingDataContract
    If composite Is Nothing Then
        Throw New ArgumentNullException("composite")
    End If
    If composite.BoolValue Then
        composite.StringValue &= "Suffix"
    End If
    Return composite
End Function

End Class
```

**IService1.vb**

```
' NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the context menu to change the interface 

name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface IService1
<OperationContract()> _
<WebGet(UriTemplate:="GetText", BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, responseformat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json)> _
Function GetText() As String

<OperationContract()> _
<WebGet(UriTemplate:="GetData?v={value}", responseformat:=WebMessageFormat.Json)> _
Function GetData(ByVal value As Integer) As String

<OperationContract()>
Function GetDataUsingDataContract(ByVal composite As CompositeType) As CompositeType

' TODO: Add your service operations here

End Interface

' Use a data contract as illustrated in the sample below to add composite types to service operations.

<DataContract()>
Public Class CompositeType

<DataMember()>
Public Property BoolValue() As Boolean

<DataMember()>
Public Property StringValue() As String
```

End Class

**Web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
      <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="httpBehavior">
                <webHttp />
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
        <service name="HttpWcfWeb.VehicleService">
            <endpoint address=""
                behaviorConfiguration="httpBehavior"
                binding="webHttpBinding"
                contract="HttpWcfWeb.IVehicleService" />
        </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

here is my android client code...

```
public static final String _URL = "http://192.168.212.37:8080/Service1.svc";
protected void logIn(){


    try
    {


// Send GET request to <service>/GetText
   HttpGet request = new HttpGet(_URL + "/GetText");
   request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
   request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

   DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
   HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();

   // Read response data into buffer
   long intCount = responseEntity.getContentLength();
     char[] buffer = new char[(int)responseEntity.getContentLength()];
     InputStream stream = responseEntity.getContent();
     InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
     reader.read(buffer);
     stream.close();

     tvStatus.append("response: ");
     JSONArray plates = new JSONArray(new String(buffer));

     for (int i = 0; i < plates.length(); ++i) {
      tvStatus.append(plates.getString(i));
     }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

For some unkown reason, I can run the VS 2010 client test and it the WCF host works fine.  The code above just returns nothing (it's supposed to return a string)

any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You posted way too much code.

Comment: Jarrette, can you pls write how you solve this problem. I trying couple days with same example, i have same problem like you, i really dont have idea what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about Android (Haven't done any WCF stuff from Android yet) but when I access some of our WCF services from javascript I have to specifically convert the output of the method to JSON before sending it back to javascript or else the JS will get nothing back.

I wonder if this may be the case here? Try returning a properly formatted JSON object?

Comment: responseEntity.getContentLength() is coming back as 0

so the responseEntity is empty coming back from the service.  The service set to send JSON and the client code is set to receive JSON. 

Very confused on this one...

Comment: Can you try sending back plain text ("text/xml") and seeing if that works? Also try changing your Content-Type to "application/json; charset=utf-8"

Comment: Something I just noticed.  In my HttpResponse, I'm getting a statusline.statusCode=400, and a statusline.reasonPhrase = "Bad Request"

Comment: Check these links. I'm not all too familiar with WCF but they may help: http://underground.infovark.com/2008/04/09/wcf-bad-request/, http://www.robbagby.com/rest/effective-error-handling-with-wcf-rest/

Comment: I think the problem is bad syntax calling the method.  The uri i'm using is "http://192.168.212.37:8080/Service1.svc/GetText"

I wonder if this is the right syntax to call that method?

Comment: You know what, I didn't even realize that. 192.x is an internal IP address, Android would not be able to access this even through the emulator (I don't think). Try access it through your external IP.

Comment: It's only internal through a VPN, the server is actually in a different city, I"m just tunneling to it.  You think it could still be a factor? 

I actually figured out how to get rid of the 400 error, I just changed the URI to the generic address:

192.168.212.37:8080/Service1.svc

But now, it's returning an HTML page, I think probably an error screen.  I just don't know how to decipher the XML that gets returned.  I am not normally a java programmer (this is my first android app), so I don't know how to parse the XML into a readable format to see what the error is...

Comment: Can you, using the Eclipse debugger, inspect the returned HTML/XML and post it here, as an update to your original question? And yes, if the device does not have an internal IP address that can access a 192.x address then it will not work :) IIRC, the emulator is not given a 192.x IP address, though I could be wrong =)

Comment: strange......
 (java.lang.String) <HTML><HEAD><link rel="alternate" type="text/xml" href="http://192.168.212.37:8080/Service1.svc?disco"/><STYLE type="text/css">#content{ FONT-SIZE: 0.7em; PADDING-BOTTOM: 2em; MARGIN-LEFT: 30px}BODY{MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-LEFT: 0px; COLOR: #000000; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana; BACKGROUND-COLOR: white}P{MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 12px; COLOR: #000000; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana}PRE{BORDER-RIGHT: #f0f0e0 1px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 5px; BORDER-TOP: #f0f0e0 1px solid; MARGIN-TOP: -5px; PADDING-LEFT: 5px; FONT-SIZE: 1.2em; PADDING-BOTTOM: 5px; BORDER-LEFT: #f0f

Comment: it must be the disco page, since I'm no longer specifying a method to consume.  I guess I'm just not real sure on the syntax to specify a method and/or parameters to the WCF.

Comment: ok, yup, it's this page:
http://wcf.virtualhealthcheck.com:8080/Service1.svc

as you can see, I know have a DNS and the service is available externally.

Comment: Hi Jarrette, I'm almost at a lost. One thing I want to point out is that when I navigate to http://wcf.virtualhealthcheck.com:8080/Service1.svc/GetText I see a blank page. I get an error if I try http://wcf.virtualhealthcheck.com:8080/Service1.svc/GetText in IE. If the service is returning blank in my browser (Google Chrome) then that why would be why Android is getting an empty string back. Maybe try removing the WebGet attribute from the method in IService1.vb?

Comment: strange, you can see the "wsdl" in IE here...
http://wcf.virtualhealthcheck.com:8080/Service1.svc?wsdl

Comment: You're welcome! What was the solution? Try posting the solution as an answer to this question so anyone else who has this problem can use it as reference :)